# Test fail with ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, null

I have on view show.html.erb

```
 <%= @question.user.lesson_id %>
```

and this is on browser a number.

my questions_controller.rb is

```
 def show
    @question = Question.find(params[:id])
    @comments = @question.comments.all
    if user_signed_in?
            @rating_currentuser = @question.ratings.find_by_user_id(current_user.id)
            unless @rating_currentuser
            @rating_currentuser = current_user.ratings.new
   end
 end
```

and my questions_controller_test.rb

```
   test "should show question signed in" do
    sign_in users(:user2)
    get :show, :id => @question_user1.to_param
    assert_response :success
   end
```

and everything is ok (browser and testing)

when change view show.html.erb

```
   <%= @question.user.lesson.name %>
```

I am OK with browser but fail testing with

```
   ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass.
```

I try this

```
  @name = Lesson.find(params[:id])
```

on questions_controller.rb then test fail with

```
  Expected response to be a <:success>, but was <302>
```

similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722629/actionviewtemplateerrorundefined-method-first-name-for-nilnilclass) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667597/actionviewtempleteerrorundefined-method-each-for-nilnilclass) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8163060/actioncontrollerroutingerroruninitialized-constant-adminscontroller)

Answer (score 2):

Using try can potentially mask the underlying problem.

For example, when I had this error it was because I wasn't creating a model object without the correct foreign key references fixed up - the view was rendering using the FK association with the name attribute - e.g. Product.ProductType.name. If I had used try to workaround it, it would have masked this fault in my test which would have been undesirable in the test. Once I had added the correct references everything worked as it should have with no need for try(:name).

Comment: Thank you for reply, in my schema.rb I have two tables. Table "lessons" with t.string "name" and table "tags" with t.string "name". Perhaps this is the issue. I try to change the database and see

Answer (score 1):

The solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3869612/how-can-i-check-for-undefined-method-for-nilclass-before-i-error-out)

is use the try method and change view as

```
<%= @question.user.lesson.try(:name) %>
```