# My test fails with ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The cause of this errors is the code inside my index page which is `<%= pin.user.name %>`.

But when I change it to `<%= pin.user.name if pin.user %>`, my tests all passed.

[Same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10840783/test-fail-with-actionviewtemplateerror-undefined-method-name-for-nilnilc) has already been posted but no accepted solution that's why I post this.

This is the full error messages:

```
ERROR["test_non-signed_in_user_layout_links", SiteLayoutTest, 1.3199719070007632]
 test_non-signed_in_user_layout_links#SiteLayoutTest (1.32s)
ActionView::Template::Error:         ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
            app/views/pins/_pin.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_pins__pin_html_erb___3167554587389080103_47088431630420'
            app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_static_pages_home_html_erb___4092361779176196837_47088431162360'
            test/integration/site_layout_test.rb:10:in `block in <class:SiteLayoutTest>'

ERROR["test_signed_in_user_layout_links", SiteLayoutTest, 2.0834625150000647]
 test_signed_in_user_layout_links#SiteLayoutTest (2.08s)
ActionView::Template::Error:         ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
            app/views/pins/_pin.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_pins__pin_html_erb___3167554587389080103_47088457226940'
            app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_static_pages_home_html_erb___4092361779176196837_47088457198480'
            test/integration/site_layout_test.rb:24:in `block in <class:SiteLayoutTest>'

ERROR["test_should_get_home", StaticPagesControllerTest, 2.1026109900003576]
 test_should_get_home#StaticPagesControllerTest (2.10s)
ActionView::Template::Error:         ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
            app/views/pins/_pin.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_pins__pin_html_erb___3167554587389080103_47088457310920'
            app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_static_pages_home_html_erb___4092361779176196837_47088457291840'
            test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:9:in `block in <class:StaticPagesControllerTest>'
```

and these are the tests that have the said errors:

> site_layout_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class SiteLayoutTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  def setup
    ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.clear
    @user = users(:john)
  end

  test "non-signed in user layout links" do
    get root_path
    assert_template 'static_pages/home'
    assert_select "a[href=?]", root_path, count: 2
    assert_select "a[href=?]", about_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", new_user_session_path, count: 2
    assert_select "a[href=?]", new_user_registration_path, count: 1
  end

  test "signed in user layout links" do
    get new_user_session_path
    assert_template 'devise/sessions/new'
    post user_session_path, params: { user: { email: @user.email, password: 'password' } }
    assert_not flash.empty?
    assert_redirected_to root_path
    follow_redirect!
    assert_template 'static_pages/home'
    assert_select "a[href=?]", new_user_session_path, count: 0
    assert_select "a[href=?]", new_user_registration_path, count: 0
    assert_select "a[href=?]", edit_user_registration_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", destroy_user_session_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", new_pin_path
  end
end
```

> static_pages_controller_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class StaticPagesControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  def setup
    @user = users(:john)
  end

  test "should get home" do
    get root_url
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", full_title
  end

  test "should get about" do
    get about_url
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", full_title("About")
  end
end
```

and these are my `users.yml`:

```
john:
  name: John Rockefeller
  email: john@rockefeller.com
  encrypted_password: <%= Devise::Encryptor.digest(User, 'password') %>
  created_at: <%= Time.zone.now %>

andrew:
  name: Andrew Carnegie
  email: andrew@carnegie.com
  encrypted_password: <%= Devise::Encryptor.digest(User, 'password') %>
  created_at: <%= Time.zone.now %>
```

and `pins.yml`

```
quote:
  description: "Lorem quote"
  created_at: <%= 10.minutes.ago %>
  user: john

recipe:
  description: "Lorem recipe"
  created_at: <%= 3.years.ago %>

most_recent:
  description: "Lorem most recent"
  created_at: <%= Time.zone.now %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you throw a `binding.pry` (assuming you have pry/byebug) about that code snippet and type `pin.user` in that situation it should say `nil`.

You will get the error you are currently getting when you try to call `.name` on `nil`. The reason your if statement saves you is that the `.name` isn't called if `pin.user` is nil.

A fix for this that is very handy in rails would be to change your code to:

`<%= pin.user.try(:name) %>` which won't raise an error but only return `nil` if `pin.user` is `nil`.

### Alternatively-

If you always want a user attached to a pin, which you do, you can prevent a user-less pin from ever coming into existence by validating that a user is associated with the pin before it's created:

```rb
class Pin < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :user, presence: true

end
```

Hope this helps!! :)

Comment: but I read that using `try`is not the real solution? which is the better solution? using `try` or just using the `<%= pin.user.name if pin.user %>`?

Comment: Unfortunately I use `rspec` and `FactoryGirl` primarily for my rails tests so I may not be able to debug these tests specifically as quick as you can.

Comment: In that case, if a `pin` must ALWAYS have a `user`, then in your case you are hitting situations where a pin does not have a user and it must have one, according to your view code. 

If there are cases where your `pin` may *not* have a `user`, then you will need to either use your `if` statement or my `try` statement, or else it will break.

You can't call a method on something that doesn't exist. :)

Comment: Does my second comment help a bit @jeramaedybohol?

Comment: Yup, my pin must always have a user that's why I used `dependent: :destroy` so that whenever a user is deleted, it's corresponding pins will also get deleted so that all pins must have a user.

Comment: If you want to prevent that error from occurring, in that case, you should validate that a pin has a user before it's created, then you'll never run into the issue that a pin has `nil` for `user`.

Comment: I have updated my answer to cover off that issue and give a code example for how to avoid it in future.

Comment: So I'm guessing it's a situation of your tests reproducing a user-less pin but in real life in your application that wouldn't happen?

Comment: I think there's no problem in my tests. Now that you explained to me why, I am now convinced that using `if` or your `try` method is the solution.